# How to show data based on weekdays Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am developing an interface in which I need to show data based on weekdays.

For some reasons it is showing them wrongly. My requirement is to show 7 boxes in each row from Monday to Sunday and show data in those day's boxes that have data saved against in them.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
    <% groups.each do |subgroups| %>
     <tr id="slot-formula-<%= subgroups.map(&:id) %>" class="subgroups move_row" title="Drag Drop To Sort Slot Formula Positions">
      <td class="graykbg">
      <p class="doorman" style="margin-top: 3px;color: #353e48;padding: 3px;">
      <%= subgroups.map(&:doorman).first == 'none' ? 'Standard' : subgroups.map(&:doorman).first.upcase %>
      </p>
     <p class="set_doorman" style="display: none;"><%= subgroups.map(&:doorman).first %></p>
    </td>
     <% weeks.zip(subgroups.sort_by {|week_day| weeks.index(week_day.day)}).each do |day, u| %>
    <% puts day.inspect, '***********************' %>
    <% puts u.inspect, '!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!' %>
     <% if day == u.try(:day) %>
     <td class="timeslots" data-id="<%= u.id %>">
     <span class="slotcheck" data-id="<%= u.id %>" data-day="<%= u.day %>"></span>
      <div>
      <p class="slots">
      <span class="slot_info"><%= "PickUp Slots: #{u.pickup_slots}" %>
      <br></span>
      <span class="slot_info"><%= "DropOff Slots: #{u.dropoff_slots}" %>
       <br></span>
      <span class="slot_info"><%= "Max Visits: #{u.max_visits}" %>
       <br></span>
       <span class="slot_info"><%= "Start Time: #{u.start_time}" %>
       <br></span>
       <span class="slot_info"><%= "End Time: #{u.end_time}" %>
       <br></span>
       <span class="slot_info"><%= "Cut Off Time: #{u.cutoff_time}" %>
       <br></span>
      <span class="slot_info"><%= "Turnaround Time: #{u.turnaround_time}" %>
      <br></span>
     <span class="slot_info"><%= "Day: #{u.day}" %></span>
      </p>
    </div>
      </td>
    <% else %>
   <td class="timeslots">
    <span class="slotcheck"></span>
     <div>
     <p class="slots">
     <span class="slot_info">1
     <br></span>
      <span class="slot_info">2
     <br></span>
    <span class="slot_info">3
    <br></span>
     <span class="slot_info">4
    <br></span>
    <span class="slot_info">5
      <br></span>
     <span class="slot_info">6
     <br></span>
    <span class="slot_info">7
     <br></span>
     <span class="slot_info">8</span>
     </p>
     </div>
   </td>
    <% end %>
   <% end %>
    <%  puts '---------------------------------------' %>
       <td>
      <button class="btn btn-sm color-red slotremove"><span class="fa fa-close"></span>
     </button>
      </td>
     </tr>
    <% end %>
```

The output of my code is:

[image]

And here is console result of puts statement.

The console is showing that there are 4 days in which the data should show properly and leave rest of them empty but it is only showing for Monday.

So, based on these results, I want that Monday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday should have data in boxes and rest of boxes should stay empty.

```
"Monday"
***********************
#<SlotFormula id: 1889, day: "Monday", pickup_slots: 1, dropoff_slots: 2, max_visits: 20, start_time: " 10:00 PM", end_time: " 11:00 PM", doorman: "none", created_at: "2018-03-05 12:07:54", updated_at: "2018-03-05 12:07:54", status: true, zone_id: 1, cutoff_time: "4:00 PM", turnaround_time: 36, position: 11>
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
"Tuesday"
***********************
#<SlotFormula id: 1890, day: "Wednesday", pickup_slots: 3, dropoff_slots: 4, max_visits: 20, start_time: " 10:00 PM", end_time: " 11:00 PM", doorman: "none", created_at: "2018-03-05 12:08:21", updated_at: "2018-03-05 12:08:21", status: true, zone_id: 1, cutoff_time: "4:00 PM", turnaround_time: 36, position: 10>
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
"Wednesday"
***********************
#<SlotFormula id: 1892, day: "Thursday", pickup_slots: 7, dropoff_slots: 8, max_visits: 20, start_time: " 10:00 PM", end_time: " 11:00 PM", doorman: "none", created_at: "2018-03-05 12:09:25", updated_at: "2018-03-05 12:09:25", status: true, zone_id: 1, cutoff_time: "4:00 PM", turnaround_time: 36, position: 8>
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
"Thursday"
***********************
#<SlotFormula id: 1891, day: "Friday", pickup_slots: 5, dropoff_slots: 6, max_visits: 20, start_time: " 10:00 PM", end_time: " 11:00 PM", doorman: "none", created_at: "2018-03-05 12:09:01", updated_at: "2018-03-05 12:09:01", status: true, zone_id: 1, cutoff_time: "4:00 PM", turnaround_time: 36, position: 9>
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
"Friday"
***********************
nil
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
"Saturday"
***********************
nil
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
"Sunday"
***********************
nil
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@phoet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100731/phoet) provided me some direction in displaying my data by right way. Though I couldn't understand his approach fully and asked as well but it has let me do what I was trying to achieve.

This is my final working code after certain refactoring. There can be many possible/best approaches to get this done in more efficient way too.

```
<% available_days = {} %>
 <% week_days = %w(Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday) %>
 <% all_days = {0 => 'Monday', 1 => 'Tuesday', 2 => 'Wednesday', 3 => 'Thursday', 4 => 'Friday', 5 => 'Saturday', 6 => 'Sunday'} %>
  <% groups.each do |subgroups| %>
  <tr id="slot-formula-<%= subgroups.map(&:id) %>" class="subgroups move_row" title="Drag Drop To Sort Slot Formula Positions">
  <td class="graykbg">
  <p class="doorman" style="margin-top: 3px;color: #353e48;padding: 3px;">
  <%= subgroups.map(&:doorman).first == 'none' ? 'Standard' : subgroups.map(&:doorman).first.upcase %>
  </p>
  <p class="set_doorman" style="display: none;"><%= subgroups.map(&:doorman).first %></p>
  </td>
  <% available_data = subgroups.sort_by {|week_day| week_days.index(week_day.day)}.each_with_index {|record, index| available_days.store(index, record.day)} %>
  <% all_days.each do |key, day| %>
  <% if available_days.has_value?(day) %>
  <% subgroup = available_data.map.select {|added_day| day == added_day.day}.first %>
  <td class="timeslots" data-id="<%= subgroup.id %>">
  <span class="slotcheck" data-id="<%= subgroup.id %>" data-day="<%= subgroup.day %>"></span>
  <div>
  <p class="slots">
  <span class="slot_info"><%= "PickUp Slots: #{subgroup.pickup_slots}" %>
  <br></span>
  <span class="slot_info"><%= "DropOff Slots: #{subgroup.dropoff_slots}" %>
  <br></span>
 <span class="slot_info"><%= "Max Visits: #{subgroup.max_visits}" %>
  <br></span>
  <span class="slot_info"><%= "Start Time: #{subgroup.start_time}" %>
  <br></span>
  <span class="slot_info"><%= "End Time: #{subgroup.end_time}" %>
 <br></span>
 <span class="slot_info"><%= "Cut Off Time: #{subgroup.cutoff_time}" %>
 <br></span>
 <span class="slot_info"><%= "Turnaround Time: #{subgroup.turnaround_time}" %>
  <br></span>
  <span class="slot_info"><%= "Day: #{subgroup.day}" %></span>
  </p>
  </div>
  </td>
  <% else %>
  <td><span class="slotcheck" data-id="" data-day="<%= day %>"></span>
  <div></div>
  </td>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <td>
  <button class="btn btn-sm color-red slotremove"><span class="fa fa-close"></span>
  </button>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
```

**The output of code is ( my desired output ):**

Only those boxes are filled that needs to be data in. Now, with that admin would be able to add data in empty boxes as it was part of initial requirement and they would be add with same sequence right below respective day.

[image]

Comment: P.S: Sometimes unresponsiveness motivates you and keep you away from giving up :-)

Answer (score 0):

your logging output shows the problem, you are using zip to create one array to iterate over, but the array of results is smaller, so the days do not line up:

```
"Tuesday"
***********************
#<SlotFormula id: 1890, day: "Wednesday"
```

instead of zipping, you should map over your result-set to create a hash with the day as key.

with that hash you can iterate over the days and access the result through a hash lookup with the day key.